# Broken img on React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to help. My problem is broken img.I work on React. How can I solve ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5szC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E06Oe.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzzoV.png)

Comment: Either the path isn't correct or the image doesn't exist.

Comment: provide more details please, what "error" in your console output?

Comment: Please read [ask]. In particular the part about not converting text to pictures.

Comment: @Medi — Nonsense. The URLs `./1.png` and `1.png` are entirely equivalent.

Comment: When you say 'path is correct' are you sure? Perhaps you could show us the full url of the image as well as adding enough code to your question so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like the path to image is broken, try to solve it
by import image in the head of the file and add image path to your `<img>` element

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png';     // <-- import image here

class test extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <img src={logo} /> // <-- add image path here
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default test;
```

docs for adding images to your react app https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

Answer (score -2):

you must import that image and set width and height for that image

import image1 from "./1.jpg";